# How to loop through a segment of list while another segment remains constant

Tags: c#, .net, list, loops, foreach

I'm trying to loop through a list as thus

```
var grp = profile.where(pro => pro.Age == AgeRange.group13_17).ToArray
```

which works fine but I also want to be able to loop through another range of values while the above query remains the same i.e while

```
pro.Age = AgeRange.group13_17
```

I want to be able to loop through every income class range belonging to the same age group. below is the structure of my list in C#

```
var IncomeAge = new List<RealIncomeAge>();
{
    IncomeAge.Add(new RealIncomeAge { RealAge = AgeRange.group18_24, RealIncome = IncomeRange.class1 });
    IncomeAge.Add(new RealIncomeAge { RealAge = AgeRange.group18_24, RealIncome = IncomeRange.class2 });
    IncomeAge.Add(new RealIncomeAge { RealAge = AgeRange.group18_24, RealIncome = IncomeRange.class3 });
    IncomeAge.Add(new RealIncomeAge { RealAge = AgeRange.group18_24, RealIncome = IncomeRange.class4 });
    IncomeAge.Add(new RealIncomeAge { RealAge = AgeRange.group18_24, RealIncome = IncomeRange.class5 });
    IncomeAge.Add(new RealIncomeAge { RealAge = AgeRange.group18_24, RealIncome = IncomeRange.class6 });
    IncomeAge.Add(new RealIncomeAge { RealAge = AgeRange.group18_24, RealIncome = IncomeRange.class7 });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Something along those lines:

```
var groups = IncomeAge.GroupBy(ia => ia.RealAge)
```

You then can do a

```
foreach (var item in groups.Where(g => g.Key.Age == AgeRange.group13_17))
  Console.WriteLine(item)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can group by age range first, and then select all elements in the group as follows:

```
//group by
var groups = IncomeAge.GroupBy(ia => ia.RealAge);

//select where age group is group18_24
foreach (var item in groups.SelectMany(ra => ra.Where(a=>a.RealAge==AgeRange.group18_24))) 
    Console.WriteLine(item.RealIncome);
```